# What is the rank and nullity of the zero matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

What is the rank and nullity of the  $2 \times 2$ matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Hint: rank is the dimension of the range. Do you know what the range of the matrix is? (Same with nullity being the dimension of the null space).

Comment: Surely you have some sort of guess... your guess is probably even correct.  If this question seems too easy, that's because it is.  All it requires is understanding definitions of terms and realizing that the space spanned by the zero vector contains only the zero vector, much like how any number times zero is still zero.

Comment: @MadhavNakar no, we have not covered the range of a matrix, but I will read up on it myself and see if it helps me figure this out. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @JMoravitz my thinking was along those lines - my guess was that it has nullity equal to 1 which, by the Dimension theorem, would imply that rank is equal to 1 -  since the sum of the rank and dimension should equal the number of columns of the matrix.

Comment: What makes you think it has rank equal to $1$?  Recall, a line is one-dimensional.  A plane is two-dimensional.  A **point** is zero dimensional.  The range contains only the single element, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, not a line or a plane of elements.  Worded a different way, what makes you think it has nullity equal to $1$?  Notice that $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and also $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the column space, the linear subspace of the codomain spanned by the columns.

For a matrix whose only entries are zero, the column space would be spanned only by zero vectors.  Any linear combination of zero vectors is again a zero vector.

The space containing only the zero vector and no others is considered to be **zero**-dimensional.  The rank is then **zero**.

---

The nullity is the dimension of the nullspace, the subspace of the domain consisting of all vectors from the domain who when the matrix is applied to it result in the zero vector.  It is clear that for $Z$ a zero matrix and any vector $v$ in the domain that $Zv=\vec{0}$ results in the zero vector and so the nullspace is the entire domain.

As such, the nullity of any matrix containing all zeroes would be the number of columns of the matrix, i.e. the dimension of the domain.

---

TLDR: The nullity of $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is $2$ while the rank is $0$.